# How to cast SQLiteDataReader values into float in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, casting, sqlite, floating-point

I am struggling with a small issue: conversion of `SqliteDataReader` values into `float`. I am demonstrating how I am trying to cast.

```
Pricing pricing = null;
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(thisApp.dbConnectionString);
try
{
   string _sql = "select * from pricing where id=@id";
   SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(_sql, con);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", myid);
   con.Open();
   SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
          pricing = new Pricing()
          {
              // "ActualPrice" in my model and "actual_price" in sqlite db are Float type.
              // But here i am getting error saying cast is not allowed
              // It tried one more way as well but didn't work.
              ActualPrice = Convert.ToInt32(reader["actual_price"])
              // OR
              ActualPrice = (float) Convert.ToInt32(reader["actual_price"])
          };
      }
   }               
 }
 catch
 {
 }
 finally
 {
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
       con.Close();
 }
 return pricing;
```

Can you help me how can I get values from `reader["actual_price]` into my property `ActualPrice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is

First try to read the column value as a string like

```
   Pricing pricing = new Pricing();
    string string_val=convert.ToString(reader["actual_price"]);
```

Then use a TryParse

If your property is of type double use double.TryParse

```
float _val=0;

float.Tryparse(string_val,out _val);
```

Then assign  model property like

```
pricing.ActualPrice =_val;
```

The benefit of doing string conversion & then Tryparse is it will helps you to handle null value exceptions

Might be this can be done in some other simpler ways as well

Comment: my property dataType is not double its float, so this double.Tryparse will work ? But i try first this solution.

Comment: Use float Trypasre [ see edit in answer] . My point is instead of trying direct type conversion Use TryParse